# Hoare triple: Loop invariant and partial correctness

Tags: logic, correctness-proof, hoare-logic, predicate-logic

Below there is Hoare triple in which variable $a$ is an array of integers, $len$, $x, i$ are integer-valued variables, and $r$ is a Boolean-valued variable. I have to provide a **loop invariant** (using **predicate logic**) suitable for proving **partial** correctness and explain in words why it is a **loop invariant** and why it is sufficient to prove **partial** correctness.

$$\begin{align*}
&\{0 ≤ len \} \\
&i = 0;  \\
&r = \textbf{false}; \\
&\textbf{while}\;(i < len)\;\{ \\
&\quad\textbf{if}\;(a[i] = x)\;\{ \\
&\quad\quad r = \textbf{true}; \\
&\quad\quad i = len; \\
&\quad \}\;\textbf{else}\;\{ \\
&\quad\quad i = i + 1;\\
&\quad \} \\
&\} \\
&\{(r=\textbf{true})\iff(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: (0 \le k \land k < len \land a[k] = x ))\}
\end{align*}$$

I tried to use **loop rule** and get the **invariant** I by the third premise:

$$\{I \land \lnot b\} \; [] \; S \; \{Q\}$$

What I did:
$$\{I \land i < len \} \implies \{(r = \textbf{true}) \iff (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}:(0 \le k \land k < len \land a[k] = x ))\}$$

I can not go anymore at here, because I do not know how to find an invariant $\land$  $a[ i ] \neq x$ $\implies$ postcondition. And if $a[ i ] \neq x$ that means this it does not find $x$ in array $a$. But the postcondition said it will find $x$ because $r = \textbf{true}$.

Comment: Try replacing $len$ with $i$ in the postcondition.

Comment: @dkaeae Sir, because the negative guard is *i* >= *len*, thus it already satisfy the postcondition, so I guess we only need to find an invariant which does not make the array be null is ok.

Comment: I meant replacing $len$ with $i$ in the $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: \cdots$ part.

Comment: @dkaeae Sir, I come up with an invariant: *i* <= *len* ∧ *i* >= *len* ∧ ∃ *k* ∈Z:( 0 ≤ *k* ∧ *k* < *i* ∧ *a* [*k*] = *x*

Comment: @BoiD A bit better: `i <= len \/ i >= len /\ ...` — note the or instead of the and, since your `i <= len /\ i >= len` gives `i = len`.

But in fact, I’d try as invariant $r = \mathit{false} \land i \le \mathit{len} \lor r = \mathit{true} \land i = \mathit{len} \land \exists k.\, \ldots$. Depending on the flag r, our invariant gives different conditions.

Comment: Also, what you must show that `I /\ not (i < len) => postcondition` — the invariant and the *negated* loop guard must imply the postcondition, because when the loop ends `I /\ not (i < len)` is what holds. Beyond my reasoning, at least Wikipedia confirms:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#While_rule

Comment: In fact, as invariant you’ll probably need something stronger I guess, like $(r = \mathit{false} \implies i \le \mathit{len}) \land (r = \mathit{true} \Leftrightarrow i = \mathit{len} \land \exists k.\, \ldots)$. Basically, this invariant contains the postcondition.
As this is a comment, it’s just a hint, not a full answer, so I haven’t tried doing a full proof and you might need further adjustments.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3165737/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/106174/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).